# how to check if php mail function succeeded and then run a javascript code?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form that is using php mail function and have a die at the end if the mail was send successfully.

can I "catch" this die event and then run a javascript in case that die actually occur?

Comment: `die(1);` then check if the response contains a 1

Comment: Using `die` for this is a great example of antipattern. Die is intended for terminating output after severe error or after sending redirect headers - and definitely not to signal that mail was sent or to pass something to javascript. The question should be different. @Dale, read the docs! Integer won't be printed.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo You're right `die('1')` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
die('<script>alert(1);</script>');
```

Comment: And what about the rest of HTML document? You assumed that output is HTML (or XHTML) by using 'script' tag, so close other tags as well!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you call die? Set a variable that the mail was sent successfully and react (if-condition) to this variable in your script. Then you can run javascript code in your script.

Comment: I totally agree (+1). Having `die('<script>something</script>')` leaves unclosed `body` and `html` tags. Even if we close them in `die`, we are not sure that there is nothing else left open (for example if we `die()` in different parts of the code, when we add some elements later etc.).

Comment: how can I react and know if mail was sent successfully?

Comment: wrap the function mail() to an if-condition. mail() is returning true on success, otherwise false... if mail() returns true, set a variable and you can check the same variable later to run javascript code. NOTE: if mail() returns true does NOT mean that the receipent got the email because there is no check if the mailaddress really exists. it just means that the outgoing mailserver sent it. read more at "Return values": http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

You can output a JSON string (or anything really) in the die call to tell JS that the mail has been sent.

```
die('{success:true}');
```

I suppose this is an AJAX request, then you can parse the JSON in the success callback.